# Using hdparam for more strenuous tests

Tags: performance, hard-drive, ssd, stress-testing

So I am tasked with getting some strenuous raw hard drive performance tests. We started with FIO but this has proven to be ineffective as the results are poor in windows and linux.

I tried Bonnie++ for testing the disk , but Bonnie++ complains about not being to cd to the directory. This tells me that a raw disk test is probably beyond the scope of that tool.

I looked to hdparam and this seems to return closer to the theoretical max read speed, but it runs for a few seconds and stops.

Is there a way to run hdparam for a long time and have more strenuous tests?

thanks

Comment: fio is the correct tool for this, hdparm is not. If you had problems with fio, you should ask about them.

Comment: As hinted at by @michael-hampton I would suggest that you ask a separate (and more direct...) question about why your `fio` runs are getting "poor" results. `fio` has lots of options (and engines) which makes it very easy to test something other than what you thought you were testing. There are lots of serious companies that have successfully used fio so the burden of proof showing its inefficacy will have to start from your side I'm afraid...